# ComboBox On Select Index Changed Event

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a problem regarding comboxBox. Basically I have two comboBoxs, one is for categories and other is for products. When I select category from first comboBox then it shows products of that category in 2nd comboxBox. It all works fine when you run the purchase form and then close it after purchasing but I have some design and using User control that my application runs as a whole and there is no need to close form just clicking on button you may be shifted to next form.
Now the actual problem is using user control when I select category then it shows products in comboBox2 and then again I select another category then products of 1st category and also the products of 2nd categoey shows in comboBox two.
I want to know how I can  show products relevant to category only?
Should I use User-Control? Because without user control it works fine.

The Reason why its giving me all products name when I select more then 2 categories because I am using While loop.
Is There Any Way to get unique results like by relationship.Putting Category ID in Product Name Table?
Help me

```
   {
        SqlCommand cmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Product_Name Where Category_Name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["ProductName"].ToString());
        }

        dr.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you fill a DataTable and then use a DataReader to add rows one by one? Can't you set `comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ProductName";  comboBox2.DataSource = dt;`? Or have a DataTable with all the `ProductName`s and filter the `DataTable.DefaultView` with the selected cathegory (something like: `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Category_Name = {comboBox1.Text}";`). Or use a DataSet and [define the relation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations) between a DataTable that holds Cathegories and the one that holds the `ProductName`s.

Comment: I am not familiar with c#

Comment: But i am trying my best to do so as you suggested

Comment: I will try it with dataset and using relationship between two tables

Comment: It's the same thing in VB.Net. Remove the semicolon (which I inserted because my hands do this on their own :) and the code is the same (you specified both tags). Creating a Relation between DataTables is a good thing. You have quite a common scenario here, though. IMO, try to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting data's in comboBox2 inside the while-loop clear the comboBox2 using comboBox2.Items.Clear(). This should solve your problem. And the solution is self-explanatory, so I think I don't need to write further explanation.

Comment: By Clearing the ComboBox2 it gives me only single product name. Suppose if i have 2 products of 1category then it shows only one product.